# Compare columns in Pandas between two unequal size Dataframes for condition check

Tags: python, pandas, loops, compare, data-files

I have two pandas DF. Of unequal sizes. For example :

```
Df1
id     value
a      2
b      3
c      22
d      5 

Df2 
id     value
c      22
a      2
```

No I want to extract from DF1 those **rows** which has the same id as in DF2. Now my first approach is to run 2 for loops, with something like :

```
x=[]
for i in range(len(DF2)):
    for j in range(len(DF1)):
        if DF2['id'][i] == DF1['id'][j]:
          x.append(DF1.iloc[j])
```

Now this is okay, but for 2 files of 400,000 lines in one and 5,000 in another, I need an efficient Pythonic+Pnadas way

Comment: Use `join` to join the datasets on `id` column. After join You will get some rows with NaN values - you should use `dropna` method. Then filter joined data - probably with `pd.apply` method.

Comment: HI @404pio this suggestion worked for me wonderfully. I think  if I could, I would have made this the answer

Comment: You can formulate answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer - it is kind of "knowledge base".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

data1={'id':['a','b','c','d'],
       'value':[2,3,22,5]}

data2={'id':['c','a'],
       'value':[22,2]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)
finaldf=pd.concat([df1,df2],ignore_index=True)
```

**Output after concat**

```
   id   value
0   a   2
1   b   3
2   c   22
3   d   5
4   c   22
5   a   2
```

**Final Ouput**

```
finaldf.drop_duplicates()

    id  value
0   a   2
1   b   3
2   c   22
3   d   5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can concat the  dataframes , then check if all the elements are [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) or not , then [`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and keep just the first occurrence:

```
m = pd.concat((df1,df2))
m[m.duplicated('id',keep=False)].drop_duplicates()
```

---

```
  id  value
0  a      2
2  c     22
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df = df1[df1.set_index(['id']).index.isin(df2.set_index(['id']).index)]
```